# Array to CSS style parameters Conversion

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have an array like

```
$data = [
'padding-top'=> '15px',
'padding-bottom'=> '15px',
];
```

How can have generated a string value like

```
"padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $data = [
    'padding-top'=> '15px',
    'padding-bottom'=> '15px',
    ];

    $string  = '';
    foreach($data  as $key => $value){
        //using php connection add the key and value with string variable
        $string .= $key.':'.$value.';';
    }

    echo $string;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `loop` through the `array` and `append` to a `string` using the **key** and **value** . -- Then print the string out...

```
<?php

$data = [
'padding-top'=> '15px',
'padding-bottom'=> '15px',
];

$padding = '';

foreach($data as $key => $value){
   $padding .= $key . ':' . $value . ';';
}

?>

<div style="<?= $padding ?>">
```